# How to remove these horizontal lines in PHPStorm?

Tags: php, ide, phpstorm

How to remove these horizontal lines in PHPStorm?

[image]

I must have searched through the entire Settings window, but I can't seem to find it. Is it even possible to remove them?

Answer (score 65, accepted):

Generally speaking there are two kinds of such separators:

**1. Actual method separators** -- they appear before method/function body. *I do not see them on your screenshot so you must have removed them already.*

It's controlled by `Settings/Preferences | Editor | General | Appearance | Show method separators` option:

[image]

**2. Other separators** -- before class/namespace/etc. *These are visible on your screenshot.*

Thing is: you cannot "remove" them in the same way -- only mask them (make invisible). For that:

1. `Settings/Preferences`
2. `Editor | Color Scheme | General`
3. `Code | Method separator color`

Either remove any assigned colors (try this first) or assign the same color as background.

[image]

Comment: Note that in PhpStorm 8, they can in fact be disabled/removed (which sounds more intuitive): that's in Editor > General > Appearance > "Show method separators".

Comment: @Sygmoral That's for **method separators** only -- will do nothing for **namespaces and classes** separators (which is what the original request is about -- see screenshot).

Comment: Ahh apologies, you're right of course. It confused me a little that your solution uses the "Method separator color". Not the most intuitive setting in PhpStorm!

Comment: In PhpStorm 10 you also need to expand "Code" from the list of submenus

Comment: Unfortunately, this does not work for me. The separators for **namespaces** and **classes** are still there.

Comment: @AndrewSavetchuk Works just fine here (PhpStorm 2021.3.2). Make sure you apply the settings. Restart the IDE just in case (was not needed here). https://i.imgur.com/U3OE6Nx.png

Comment: @LazyOne Thank you! The "Apply" button didn't work for some reason, but when I clicked "OK", the separators disappeared.